# How to read local JSON file in an Angular Library?

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation, angular-library

I am trying to read a JSON file in an Angular 8 library which I am creating. I want to read the JSON file to load translations and implement internationalization for one of the component in the library.

Additional information:
The JSON file is present in the src folder only, and I want to read its content and load translations in my service.

Comment: you can use `httpClient` and call the `get(filePath/fileName.json)`

Comment: `this.http.get('./assets/data.json')`

Comment: @kardon63 I get 404 error, when I run an angular application which uses the component from my library which is trying to get translation.

Comment: @NicholasK I get 404 error. I guess in libraries we don't have assets and can expose them to be available publicly in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-json-file-aintis?file=src/app/json-typings.d.ts) write one service to read json and you can use httpclient to reach json

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class JsonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    getData(url): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(url);
    }

}
```

then in component take from service

```
constructor(private json: JsonService ) {
    json.getData('/url').subscribe((result)=> {
      console.log(result)
    });
  }
```

[Demo2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-json-file-9besu6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

As a second way you can open `"resolveJsonModule": true` in `"compilerOptions"`

and call in component like

```
import * as employeeData from "./test.json";
```

Comment: I get 404 error, when I run an angular application which uses the component from my library which is trying to get translation.

Comment: I added demo for u check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-local-json-file-aintis?file=src/app/json-typings.d.ts

Comment: Could you create a similar demo for angular library reading a json file, since in library we don't have any public folders like "assets" folder.

Comment: I added demo and second way for this. You can check it @TarunChopra

Comment: Thanks, the second way works for me. :)
Any similar approach for reading files apart from json files in angular library?